# How can I specify waypoints when starting the navigation intent?

Tags: google-gdk

I can start the navigation to a latitude/longitude point with no problems like this:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=40.774472,-73.970304&mode=w"));
        startActivity(intent);
```

- How can I add waypoints? Or how can I guide the user through the exact route I need them to go?
- What other parameters besides q can I use?
- What maps interface is being used here? Is it documented anywhere?

I've tried added some standard maps arguments and it doesn't work.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the Google Maps APIs to do what you want. Here is a link directly to the [navigation with waypoints documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#Waypoints) (you can go back up to see all the documentation for the maps APIs).

Comment: I did try adding that to the Uri.parse() method when creating the intent but then the Navigation app didn't load.  Is that what you mean?